# Fixed y-position while dragging

Tags: html, css

I added a draggable image to my website. However, I want this image to only drag horizontally and not vertically. How can I achieve that?

I currently have images that can be freely positioned on my website. However, I want to restrict them so that they can only be moved horizontally for positioning. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please attach some code to your question? It helps a lot!